# Скло (вкрилося конденсатом) - як сказати одним словом?

Tags: вживання-слів, одним-словом

Підкажіть, будь ласка, слово, що вживається у побуті і означає "вкритися конденсатом", наприклад, коли в холодну погоду на склі осідає "туман" з вологи?

What is the Ukrainian word for "mist over", when a window is covered with a mist in cold weather.

Comment: «Спітніло» здається вам занадто тілесним? А даремно, саме так воно й буде, так і треба казати.

Comment: Так от «спітніло/запітніло» й є тим самим словом, яке ви шукаєте. Я не хочу оформлювати це як відповідь.

Comment: Відповідь внизу — вірна. «Спітніти» може людина, а «запітніти» — скло.

Comment: Ну, насправді, СУМ для "спітніти" дає третє значення "Укритися краплями осілої пари"... Але саме краплями й це якось художньо з моєї точки зору... Зі склом не можу такого уявити (у прикладах там шибки й стіни)... Чи варто таке додавати у відповідь?..

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko Технічно туман - це дуже маленькі крапельки. Я теж думав написати про краплі вологи, але не став, бо краплі зазвичай видно неозброєним оком. Можливо вони все-таки вирішили написати про краплі.

Comment: @Artemix Я тому й питаю, чи варто додавати - тобто це явно відповідь на ширше питання, ніж поставлене. Але сам факт, що хтось запропонував "спітніло" може означати, що корисно додати...

Comment: @YellowSky Я поясню свою проблему, думаю що вона може бути типовою. Українська мова для мене не рідна, і хоча я навчався в українській школі, писав твори з літератури і таке інше - я ніколи не спілкувався українською мовою у сім'ї, тим більше що мої батьки її не знають. Тому, хоча я можу спілкуватися на наукові теми, щодо побутової лексики в мене є великий пробіл. Так само з англійською - можеш розповідати про "London is a capital of the Great Britain", але не знаєш як сказати "передайте мені сметану". Думаю що люди що вивчають (і іноземці) також матимуть багато питань з побутової лексики.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Запітніти](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapitnity):

(1) Стати вологим від пари, що осіла, дрібної роси.

Коли йдеться про щось, що покривається великими краплинами, можна використовувати слово "[спітніти](http://sum.in.ua/s/spitnity)":

(2) тільки 3 ос. Укритися краплями осілої пари; запотіти.

Але основне значення слова "спітніти": вкриватися потом, тому варто бути обережним, і вживати "запітніти" в цих випадках не буде помилкою.

Answer (score 5):

Я би сказав у першу чергу:
"[Запотіти](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapotity)"  і "[Запотівати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapotivaty)"

Слово "[Запітніти](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapitnity)" рідко вживається у даному контексті.

Я ніколи не чув, щоб хтось казав у побуті - "У нас вікна запітніли в машині."
Проте часто і, як б сказав, завжди вживається варіант
"У нас вікна запотіли в машині."

Answer (score 4):

Як альтернатива, скло може бути "[Запароване](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaparuvaty)".